# How can I draw an open curve which is filled by a brush in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, curve

I'm programming in Qt and I need to draw a curve which is open and fill it with a brush color.
I don't want it to be closed like a polygon.
Considering my curve is a sinusoid, also I want to fill only the upper half of the curve (the parts above the X axis)

Comment: A picture of what you want done, perhaps drawn in paint, would help.

Comment: Something like the vertical curves in the left of the picture: http://www.halliburton.com/public/landmark/contents/Overview/images/promaxvsp3.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QPainterPath`, [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html#arcTo-2) is documentation link. QPainterPath has `quadTo` and `cubicTo` method which can draw curve.

Documentation also has some nice example code which behaves as you are lookig for